# Electron Three js

Tags: node.js, three.js, electron

I have an app develop on electron and i am trying to use three js.

The issue is this 'Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "three". Relative references must start with either "/", "./" or "../""

Please, help, i dont know how many differents things i tried to make it work.

I am calling this render.js from html like this:

```
<script type="module"  src="./scripts/render.js"></script>
```

and i am importing libraries like this:

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { OrbitControls } from 'three/addons/controls/OrbitControls.js';
```

Answer (score 0):

Im sorry I dont have enough reputation to leave a comment but have you tried using THREE.JS from a website, such as by this:

```
import * as THREE from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.124/build/three.module.js';
import { OrbitControls } from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.124/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';
```

I had this exact same issue and this seemed to resolve it for me. This example uses an older version of THREE.JS but it does work

Answer (score 0):

You can add your modules like this - html file:

```
<script type="importmap">
  {
    "imports": {
      "three": "./node_modules/three/build/three.module.js",
      "OrbitControls": "./node_modules/three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js",
      "FBXLoader": "./node_modules/three/examples/jsm/loaders/FBXLoader.js",
      "Stats": "./node_modules/three/examples/jsm/libs/stats.module.js"
    }
  }
</script>
```

(Assumming you're installng three.js with npm)

js files:

```
import * as THREE from 'three'

import { OrbitControls } from 'OrbitControls'

import Stats from 'Stats'

import { FBXLoader } from 'FBXLoader'
```

That works for basic three.js modules, but depending on how exports made in other modules - might not work.

Alternative for other modules - just basic script tag

```
<script src="./node_modules/mousetrap/mousetrap.min.js" type="module"></script>
```